# Extension of prime ideals in Dedekind domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

In various textbooks and lecture notes on algebraic number theory, I have found the following claim without proof:

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain with field of fractions $F$ and let $S$ be its integral closure in some finite separable extension $E/F$. If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal in $R$, then $\mathfrak{p}S$ has a prime factorization in $S$.

My problem is here that the authors seem to assume implicitly that $\mathfrak{p}S$ is a proper ideal in $S$. (Otherwise, I think the claim is false.) Up to now, I have never seen a proof that $\mathfrak{p}S$ is indeed proper in $S$. So, why is this true? For me, this is not obvious.

$\textbf{Edit:}$ To clarify the references, I have found this claim for example in the lecture notes "Algebraic Number Theory" by John Milne, ch. 3, section "Factorization in extensions" (see here: http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf).

Comment: Do we know that $\mathfrak pS\cap R=\mathfrak p$?  If so it would follow from that, no?

Comment: @GregoryGrant: In the setting which I described, we do not now that $\mathfrak{p}S\cap R=\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Are you saying it's not true or we just don't know that it's true?

Comment: I do not see what would not be true.  Every *nonzero* ideal in a Dedekind doman is a product of prime ideals, this includes the full ring.

Comment: I mean that we just don't know it.

Comment: @quid: I only know the theorem: in a dedekind domain, every proper, nonzero ideal factors into primes. See e.g. wikipedia on dedekind domains.

Comment: @quid If that were true then we could write $1$ as a product of primes in $\mathbb Z$, since $\mathbb Z$ is, afterall, a dedekind domain.

Comment: @GregoryGrant exactly! And this is the convention most everybody uses.

Comment: @quid I don't understand your comment to me.  I thought I was saying your earlier comment is not correct, so if you agree with me then I'm confused, is it true or not that $1$ is a product of primes in $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes it is true. It is the empty product.

Comment: @quid That's evading the question, because it still does not answer the question of whether the lift of a prime ideal from $R$ to $S$ can be equal to the whole ring.  If it can happen then please post a counter-example.

Comment: @GregoryGrant of course the lift of  a prime ideal in that situation cannot equal the full ring. My point was to point out that an author saying that $pS$ has a factorization into prime ideals does not in doing so assert implictly that $pS$ is not the full ring. // See Theorem 3.20 in the linked to notes to see that the convention is used that the full ring is a product of prime ideals.

Comment: @quid Again I think the meat of the question is not the definitions but whether or not a prime ideal can lift to the full ring.  I think we all believe that it cannot but so far most of what people have posted is not relevant to that specific question - the exception being the answer posted by Bernard.

Comment: @GregoryGrant in OP it says "My problem is here that the authors seem to assume implicitly that pS is a proper ideal in S. (Otherwise, I think the claim is false.)" The believe expressed in parenthesis is false. I pointed this out. This notwithstanding, it is in fact true that pS is a proper ideal. Still that false believe might contribute to OP's confusion in studying the material, which is why I wanted to clear it up.

Comment: @quid I think you have to be a bit more precise, because it's not enough to say *everything* is a product of primes because $1$ is the *empty product*.  What then do we do with $-1$?  Or with $i$ in $\mathbb Z[i]$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant if you would stop mixing prime ideals and prime elements by referring to both of them as primes there would be less confusion. The full ring, which is the ideal generated by $1$, is the empty product of prime *ideals.*  The element $1$ is the empty product of (prime) elements.  In a Dedekind domain every nonzero ideal is the product of prime ideals. In a UFD every nonzero element is the product of a unit and product of prime elements from a fixed set of representatives.   Please see how the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic is stated in the linked to notes right at the start.

Comment: @quid I relent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\mathfrak p S=S$, then $\mathfrak p S_\mathfrak p=S_\mathfrak p$, and, as $S_\mathfrak p$ is a finitely generated $R_\mathfrak p$-module, there results by Nakayama's lemma that $S_\mathfrak p=0$, which contradicts the fact that $R_\mathfrak p\to S_\mathfrak p$ is injective.

Comment: Maybe that this is a silly question: What do mean with $S_{\mathfrak{p}}$? I am asking since $\mathfrak{p}$ is first of all an ideal in $R$.

Comment: It's the  localisation of $S$ (considered as an $R$-module) at $\mathfrak p$. Didn't you have lectures on modules of fractions?

Comment: Rings of fractions yes, but not modules of fractions. But give me some time and I'll just go through the relevant definitions.

Comment: It's is the same construction and amounts to tensoring with $A_\mathfrak p$. Any way, $S$ is aring, and $R\setminus\mathfrak p$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $S$.

Comment: Ok. I think I see the point: We can simply view $S$ as ring and consruct the ring of fractions $(R\setminus \mathfrak{p})^{-1}S$. Then, we view this ring as an $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$-module and denote it with $S_{\mathfrak{p}}$. Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: @russoo: Absolutely.

Comment: Now, your argument really makes sense to me. Therefore, I re-accept it! Thx!

Comment: By the way, note it has nothing to do with Dedekind domains: it's true for any finite integral extension of a noetherian ring. You might be interested in looking for information on the web about `going-up` and `going-down` theorems?

Answer (score 2):

Your claim holds for any *integral* ring extension $R\subset S$. If $p$ is a prime ideal of $R$, then $pS\ne S$ for there is a prime ideal $P$ of $S$ such that $P\cap R=p$.

Moreover, the following holds:

> If $R\subset S$ is an integral ring extension, $I\subseteq R$ an ideal, and $x\in IS$, then there is $n\ge1$ and $a_r\in I^r$ for $r=1,\dots,n$ such that $$x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n=0.$$

This proves that $IS\ne S$ unless $I=R$.